# Shouldn't the text change color after hovering "box"?

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE

```
<div class="box">
<p class="turn">shou</p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.turn {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:150px;
    color: white;
}
.box {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-color: blue
}
.box:hover ~ .turn {
    color: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sH3Dh/1/)

So, using my logic, after hovering on the div "box" text is supposed to turn red.
I'm quite unsure why it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using sibling selector `~` but `.turn` is a child of `.box` element. So you need to use child selector i.e. `>`.

```
.box:hover > .turn {
    color: red;
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sH3Dh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

`~` is the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). `.turn` is not a sibling of `.box`, so the style doesn't get applied.

You could use `.box:hover .turn`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong selector:

This will work!

```
.box:hover > .turn {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
.box:hover .turn{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: I think it would also help to explain what was wrong with the original attempt, rather than just posting some modified code. Look to Sachin's answer as an example of a good explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
    .box .turn:hover{
        color: red;
    }
```

> Also u can use:

```
.box p.turn:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

> if you can use padding on .box so use this

```
.box:hover >p.turn{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution if the OP wants the style to change when `.box` is hovered. adding padding to `.box` doesn't work with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

`~` CSS selector is called the [Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

If your markup (HTML) were like this:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
<p class="turn">shou</p>
```

then your CSS would work perfectly because in the DOM tree, the `<p>` node is a sibling of the `<div>` node.

DOM Tree for above HTML:

```
     <document-root>
            |
            |
     _______|_______
    |              |
  <div>           <p>
```

But in your markup, the `<p>` element is actually a child node of the `<div>`. And the DOM tree would be:

```
     <document-root>
            |
            |
          <div>
            |
            |
           <p>
```

So you should use a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) `>` since the `<p>` is a direct child or you could simple leave a space between `.box` and `.turn` (this is the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)).

So your final CSS should be:

```
.turn {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:150px;
    color: white;
}
.box {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-color: blue
}
.box:hover .turn {
    color: red;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sH3Dh/7/

Answer (score -1):

No...because `~` is a sibling selector whereas, in your example, the `.turn` element is a child of `.box`

[**http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: so... what is your proposed solution then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he didnt mention the solution as there where already enough answers.

Comment: Exactly, plus the linked article has plenty of examples. OP didn't ask for a solution, just an explanation.